# Google API. No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-search-console

I am trying to connect to google search console API using `OAuth2`

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

const searchconsole = google.webmasters({ version: 'v3', auth })

console.log(searchconsole.sites.list({}))
```

But I get this:

```
'Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set.'
```

I can not find a solid reference to this, I read that refresh token is deprecated, is this even possible to get the list of sites from node backend without interaction on the front end?

Comment: I updated answer with [generateAuthUrl] .

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error. Turns out I wasn't setting the token correctly.

I had created the Auth URL, gotten the tokens back in the response and stored them, as shown in the quickstart.

But I hit this error when I was trying to use them. I was doing this which was wrong and gave me the error:

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials(accessToken);
```

And getting the error.

After I found this link with a nice sample - https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/tasks/index.html#samples, I saw that you have to set the token as an object.

Like this:

```
 oauth2Client.setCredentials(
    {
      access_token: accessToken
    }
  );
```

That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is best reference site for google api :
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/tasks/index.html#samples

Try this :

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

// generate a url that asks permissions for webmaster ao any other google api scopes.

const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmaster'
];

const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
  access_type: 'offline',
  // If you only need one scope you can pass it as a string
  scope: scopes
});
```

OR

Try with token:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Tasks API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listConnectionNames);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

function listConnectionNames(auth) {
  const service = google.people({version: 'v1', auth});
  // ....

}
```

Comment: I get the exact same error `No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set.`

Comment: But can this be done in the backend with out pop ups?

Comment: No this is Oauth2 the consent screen must be shown to the user in a browser window.

Comment: @DalmTo But how do you do it then? is it back end or front end? Last time I checked fs is not available on front end

Comment: This is Node.js - Every time when you have running with `./node some.js` it is native terminal node.js proccess. This file credentials.json you will download from google api console for your current application.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should conslult the [google drive quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) it will show you how to set up authorization.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}
```

there is also [webmasters query.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/samples/webmasters/query.js)

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');

const webmasters = google.webmasters('v3');

async function runSample() {
  // Obtain user credentials to use for the request
  const auth = await authenticate({
    keyfilePath: path.join(__dirname, '../oauth2.keys.json'),
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly',
    ],
  });
  google.options({auth});

  const res = await webmasters.searchanalytics.query({
    siteUrl: 'http://jbeckwith.com',
    requestBody: {
      startDate: '2018-01-01',
      endDate: '2018-04-01',
    },
  });
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data;
}

if (module === require.main) {
  runSample().catch(console.error);
}
module.exports = runSample;
```

I would go with the first example as its shows how to store your authorization. The second one isnt going to do that.

## Access without authorization

If we check the documentation for [sites.list](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sites/list) you will notice it stats

[image]

This method operates on private user data you will need permission of a user with access in order to access this data.

Comment: Thanks, actually the second one worked, but it popped a browser window for authentification, how  can this work on the back end?

Comment: I guess my question is, can I use this code on node back end without the user having to authenticate?

Comment: No. Webmasters data is private user data, you need the permission of the user in order to access that data

Comment: Right, so in that case I am better off using the `gapi` example in the front end anyways?

Comment: it wont matter you still need to be authorized

Comment: If I run the first example on the node back end on a production server how can it trigger a browser window for authentification?

Comment: you authorize it once locally then store the refresh token in the file and the backend system will use that after the fact.

Comment: So you cannot put all that code in the back end only, there needs to be split between the front and back end? I am confused where does this code goes, on react or the node back end?

Comment: Sure you can as long as your have created a refresh token and stored it on the server you dont need the front end if this is just a cron job you can leave it there and it will work fine with the refresh token once the app is in prodcution.

Comment: But if this is running on the back end where is the browser window coming from for the initial authentification?

Comment: This code is intended for installed application single user.   It is not intended as a web server application. There for you run it once on your own machine then upload your code to the server and have it running there as a cron job.

Comment: I am using a web application with a react front end and a node back end where it loads the sites from GSC as a list, could you please point me in the right direction to achieve that, I know I can run the GAPI on the front end, but I wonder if I could run it on the back end and keep all the IDs private?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this even tho everything was being set correctly. What I didn't realize was it wasn't done setting the credentials when I made the call. I solved my issues by creating a stand alone async function.

so the code looked like this:

```
const accessToken = req.body.data.access_token;

setToken(accessToken);

const gmail = google.gmail({version: "v1", auth: oauth2Client});
...
```

and

```
async function setToken(accessToken) {
  try {
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({access_token: accessToken});
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

With this function, it waits for `setCredentials` to finish before calling the gmail api.

Hope this helps!