# Authorize Gmail API using Oauth2 failing Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, gmail

I've tried the soultion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70862741/google-api-no-access-refresh-token-api-key-or-refresh-handler-callback-is-set) and it isn't working for me.

I've tried revoking access to my app and reauthorizing and it's not working either. Here is my auth code:

```
export function handleAuth() {
  const oauth2Client = getOAuth2Client();

  const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',

    scope: ['https://mail.google.com/'],
  });
}
```

I take the URL returned from this and use it to auth my gmail account. Then I have the auth callback:

```
  app.get('/oauth2callback', async (req, res) => {
    const query = req.query;
    const code = query.code as string;

    const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token,
    });
  });
```

And I have a listener waiting for new tokens:

```
  oauth2Client.on('tokens', async (tokens) => {
    if (tokens.refresh_token) {
      oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token,
      });

      if (tokens.access_token && tokens.refresh_token) {
        const tokenRepo = getCustomRepository(GcpTokenRepository);
        await tokenRepo.create({
          log in my db...
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Then when I try and run the `watch` method so I can listen to emails:

```
  async watch() {
    const gmail = await this.authGmail(); // method that returns type Promise<gmail_v1.Gmail>
    const res = await gmail.users.watch({
      userId: 'me',
      requestBody: {
        labelIds: ['INBOX'],
        topicName: `topic name`,
      },
    });
    console.log(' Watch re-initialized!', res);
  }
```

And this watch method throws the error: `Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set`

When I console log my `auth` variable returned from `google.auth.OAuth2()` I also notice the `credentials` field is an empty object...

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your callback() ?

```
app.get('/oauth2callback', async (req, res) => {
    const query = req.query;
    const code = query.code as string;

    const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token,
    });
  });
```